# sort user in admin by meta value for users.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom search for users in admin dashboard and using this:
I added this to in functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_query','ba_admin_posts_filter' );
add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );
function ba_admin_posts_filter( $query )
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'];
    if (isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '')
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
}
function ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_key FROM '.$wpdb->usermeta.' ORDER BY 1';
    $fields = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N);
    print_r($fields);
?>
<select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME">
<option value=""><?php _e('Filter By Custom Fields', 'baapf'); ?></option>
<?php
    $current = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']:'';
    $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (substr($field[0],0,1) != "_"){
        printf
            (
                '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                $field[0],
                $field[0] == $current? ' selected="selected"':'',
                $field[0]
            );
        }
    }
?>
</select> <?php _e('Value:', 'baapf'); ?><input type="TEXT" name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE" value="<?php echo $current_v; ?>" />
<?php
}
```

By this I am getting custom field in select box and a text box for manual entry but it is not sorting user table according to custom field value.
for example if any user have meta value like "student", the list should be sort by the student.
what should I do to make it fine.....Help will be appreciated..

Comment: xpost: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/138352

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, the `ORDER BY 1` in your SQL prevents it.

You should replace this clause with actual sorting, `ORDER BY 1` means, that the query results will be sorted (ascending by default) by the first column of the table, in this case is `meta_key`.